# Add atribute to a existing user in LDAP with JAVA

Tags: java, ldap

i'm trying to modify a existing user and add a attribute to him. I'm using the following code:

```
Attributes attrs1 = new BasicAttributes(true);
attrs1.put("proxyHash", generateProxyHash(account, "123456"));
ldapContext.modifyAttributes(username, DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,attrs1);
```

But i've received an exception that says 'the attribute proxyHash is not allowed'

Thansks

Comment: The problem was resolved. The user I was trying to change was in a diferent schema, this schema haven't the attribute specified. After this fix the code works. Thks!

Comment: Joao Carlos: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joao Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457626/joao-carlos) found solution himself:
The user I was trying to change was in a different schema, this schema haven't the attribute specified. After this fix the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the entry `username` has the objectClass `extensibleObject` or the objectClass that requires or allows the `proxyHash` attribute the directory server must reject the attempt to add `proxyHash` to the entry.